Compile attempt throws syntax error in vs2019 file
I have been working with project ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.sln for several days now w/o any problems.
The subject issue has only manifested recently, which is:
Any attempt to Win32 compile a source file in vs2019 IDE throws the following error:
Build started...                                                                                                                                                                                          
1>------ Build started: Project: ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------                                                                                                               
1>ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.cpp                                                                                                                                                                             
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sal.h(2361,1): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'                               
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sal.h(2361,8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>Done building project "ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.vcxproj" -- FAILED.                                                                                                                                      
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The problem is strictly repeatable for ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.cpp and for any other source file in the same directory as ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.cpp.
The problem DOES NOT manifest for other source files referenced by ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.sln but not in the same directory as ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.cpp.
The problem DOES NOT manifest for any other project in my collection of Win32 apps I have developed.
I am running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE on a 64-bit HP laptop running 64-bit Windows 11.
REMEDY ATTEMPTS:
I had expected the compile attempt to complete w/o this anomaly, just as it had prior to 2 days ago.
I "repaired" vs2019 using ->Settings->Apps->InstalledApps, but doing so did not eliminate the anomaly.
Next, I examined C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\sal.h in Ultraedit but could not identify the alleged problem.
One is permitted to edit sal.h, but write access is not permitted.
Placing an editable copy of sal.h in a directory ahead of >C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include was not successful.
Among other questions already asked on StackOverflow, "C++ SAL.h errors in MSVC standard library"
had seemed promising but did not provide me any insight.

So you're saying that the exact same file compiles in one directory and not another? What is line 2361 of sal.h?

RE:Here are some lines of sal.h which relate to the subject error.
#define __specstrings

#ifdef  __cplusplus // [
#ifndef __nothrow // [
# define __nothrow __declspec(nothrow)
#endif // ]
extern "C" {
#else // ][
#ifndef __nothrow // [
# define __nothrow
#endif // ]
#endif  /* __cplusplus */ // ]

Line 2361 is the line that reads   extern "C" {

And the other question? Show us a [mcve] that works in one directory and not the other. Tell us the directory name and it's relation to the rest of the project.

If you can't show us the code that causes the issue there's little we can help you with. You say it has something to do with the directory but I don't believe that. I don't think you've tried to systematically narrow down the problem. If the directory is actually the cause then a single file with the same contents would compile in one directory and not the other.

Please read my response as of 13 minutes ago.  I tried moving the source and include files to separate directories and revising Solution Explorer to reference them.  Compile attempts on the source files in the separate directory yielded the same error message re sal.h.   As to "I don't think you've tried to systematically narrow down the problem. ",  what would you sugges that I do.  As to "If you can't show us the code that causes the issue there's little we can help you with. ",  I would gladly send you all relevant files if I knew how to do so.

You can edit your question to add details and add code. Reading through [mcve] can help you with the process of narrowing down the issue to a small example.

The cause of the problem turned out to be a stray text fragment in resource.h file.  Once said text fragment was removed, the subject problem disappeared.
